# startservice not working in Android

Tags: android, service

I am new in Android. Now i am doing one project using Service class.In my application contains one **ListView** .When we click on the item in the list view one Service class will be start.

But some problems occurring in that place.At the time of first app open the Service class will be work. But if we go back and again press on the ListView the Service class not working. ie, it is not calling that time.Why this problem occurring. Please  help me. Code is given below.

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String item=pat_id[arg2];
        CommonClass.item=item;
        System.out.println("item 1" +CommonClass.item);
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LocationService.class));

        //new Async_view_report().execute(rep_url,item,CommonClass.doctor_id);
    }


});
}
```

Comment: please put your service class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you start the `Service`, it keeps running in the background until you call `stopSelf()`. If you try to start the service again, while it's still running, it won't work. In that case you should use `bindService()`. My advice is to stop the service when you have done your operations.

Comment: yes.I declared service in manifest file          <service  android:enabled="true"    android:name=".LocationService"></service>

Comment: Hi any problem for running Async task inside of service class.Here one Async task is caaling in service class

Comment: That's not true, you should read `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html?hl=es-419#startService(android.content.Intent)`. `Every call to this method will result in a corresponding call to the target service's onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method` even if the service is running

Answer (score 49):

Try declaring service in Manifest file with full address ,
for example:-

```
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.LocationService"></service>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, I forgot to add to Manifest after a copy+paste from other project but accepted answer isn't even true

Answer (score -2):

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String item=pat_id[arg2];
        CommonClass.item=item;
        System.out.println("item 1" +CommonClass.item);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LocationService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    });
```

Try this